# sending to queue with and without selector creates big queue

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have 2 consumers in my system, that consume from same destination, but some of the messages have specific selector, and some of them not.
as a result, i see that a lot of messages are stuck in the selector consumer(they are not matching the selector)

something like that:

```
consumer1: myMessageType = 'Funny'
consumer2: myMessageType = 'Sad'
consumer3: no selector defined

Message 1 : myMessageType = 'Funny'
Message 2 : myMessageType = 'Funny'
Message 3 : myMessageType = 'Sad'
Message 4 : myMessageType = 'Sad'
Message 5 : myMessageType = 'Weird'
Message 6 : myMessageType = 'Weird'
```

and when i look at the queue(hawtio console), i see that consumer 1 and 2 have a lot of messages in queue, and they cannot consume them because lack of selector in the messages
why is that? am i abusing the amq system?

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using?

Comment: You say that "the messages have specific selector," but a selector isn't set on a _message_. A selector is set on a consumer and it selects messages based on the message's _properties_. Can you clarify what you mean here?

Comment: Are you using JMS or something else?

Comment: i'm using AMQ 5.16.3, and yes you are right, the selector is on the consumer but i add them also to specific messages as well(string properties), and yes i'm using jms template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queues can only provide messages to consumers within the maxPageSize. This is done for performance reasons-- to avoid scanning the entire data store for messages. If consumers are starved of messages, it means you have a gap in your consumer selector coverage.

You either need to:

1. Add a consumer with a selector that catches all the 'rest' of messages
2. Move to server-side filtering of messages using filtered composite destinations
3. Add a content-based router (ie Camel, Mule, etc) to sort messages into individual queues for consumers so they do not need selectors.

There is a pretty good case to be made that options #2 and #3 are cleaner architecture than trying to solve it with #1, since it puts all the information about the selectors in one place, vs scattered in different consumer configurations.